# Continuous modification of a set of points - find all nearest neighbors

Tags: optimization, tree, kdtree, voronoi

I have a 3D set of points.  These points will undergo a series of tiny perturbations (all points will be perturbed at once).  Example: if I have 100 points in a box, each point may be moved up to, but no more than 0.2% of the box width in each iteration of my program.

After each perturbation operation, I want to know the new distance to each point's nearest neighbor.

This needs to use a very fast data structure; I'm optimizing this for speed.  It's a somewhat tricky problem because I'm modifying all points at once.  Approximate NN algorithms are not suitable for this problem.

I feel like the answer is somewhere between kd-trees and Voronoi tessellations, but I am not an expert on data structures, so I am baffled about what to do.  I sure this is a very hard problem that would require a lot of research to reach a *truly* optimal solution, but even something fairly optimal will work for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try a quadkey or monster curve. It reduce the dimension and fills the plane. Microsoft bing maps quadkey is a good start to learn.